# Unexpected error when sorting an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array in Javascript but something goes wrong and I can't figure out why. The problem is that the output is wrong, because some of the array elements are marked as "undefined" and have no value after I call the myFunc function. What I expect to see is the elements sorted in descending order. But instead of that I get some of the fields with the text "undefined" in them.

here you the Javascript code:

```
var arr = [1, 123, 2, 321, 341, 2];
/*var arr = [];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 123;
arr[2] = 2;
arr[3] = 321;
arr[4] = 341;
arr[5] = 2;*/

function selectionsort(){
    var n = 6;
    for(var i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        var index = i;
        for(var j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(arr[index]<arr[j])
            {
                index = j;
            }
        }
        console.log(arr[index]);
        if(index != i)
        {
            var temp = arr[j];
            arr[i] = arr[index];
            arr[index] = temp;
        }
    }
}

function initFunc()
{
        document.getElementById("asdf").innerHTML = arr[0];
        document.getElementById("asdf1").innerHTML = arr[1];
        document.getElementById("asdf2").innerHTML = arr[2];
        document.getElementById("asdf3").innerHTML = arr[3];
        document.getElementById("asdf4").innerHTML = arr[4];
        document.getElementById("asdf5").innerHTML = arr[5];

        document.getElementById("demoto+0").innerHTML = arr[0];
        document.getElementById("demoto+1").innerHTML = arr[1];
        document.getElementById("demoto+2").innerHTML = arr[2];
        document.getElementById("demoto+3").innerHTML = arr[3];
        document.getElementById("demoto+4").innerHTML = arr[4];
        document.getElementById("demoto+5").innerHTML = arr[5]; 
}

function myFunc(){  
        document.getElementById("demoto+0").innerHTML = arr[0];
        document.getElementById("demoto+1").innerHTML = arr[1];
        document.getElementById("demoto+2").innerHTML = arr[2];
        document.getElementById("demoto+3").innerHTML = arr[3];
        document.getElementById("demoto+4").innerHTML = arr[4];
        document.getElementById("demoto+5").innerHTML = arr[5];     

        selectionsort();

        document.getElementById("asdf").innerHTML = arr[0];
        document.getElementById("asdf1").innerHTML = arr[1];
        document.getElementById("asdf2").innerHTML = arr[2];
        document.getElementById("asdf3").innerHTML = arr[3];
        document.getElementById("asdf4").innerHTML = arr[4];
        document.getElementById("asdf5").innerHTML = arr[5];
}
```

and that's the html page that is manipulated:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunc()">click</button>
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="order">
            <ul id="boxes">
            <li><div id="demoto+0" class="transperant"></div></li>
            <li><div id="demoto+1" class="transperant"></div></li>
            <li><div id="demoto+2" class="transperant"></div></li>
            <li><div id="demoto+3" class="transperant"></div></li>
            <li><div id="demoto+4" class="transperant"></div></li>
            <li><div id="demoto+5" class="transperant"></div></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        <br>
            <div class="order2">
            <ul id = "boxes">
            <li><div id="asdf" class="transperant">S</div></li>
            <li><div id="asdf1" class="transperant">S</div></li>
            <li><div id="asdf2" class="transperant">S</div></li>
            <li><div id="asdf3" class="transperant">S</div></li>
            <li><div id="asdf4" class="transperant">S</div></li>
            <li><div id="asdf5" class="transperant">S</div></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to reinvent the wheel? Just use

```
[1, 123, 2, 321, 341, 2].sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
```

Comment: It's not much about reinventing the wheel: to sort an array of numeric entries there are faster ways than using `sort`.

Comment: Micro-optimizations in the majority of use-cases. The root of all evil and what not.

Comment: @MaxArt Well, you can always explore other sorting algorithms, like http://blog.mgechev.com/2012/11/24/javascript-sorting-performance-quicksort-v8/, but I doubt that you would gain anything for such a small/trivial array.

Comment: @KooiInc Indeed, that array is way to short to show any visible benefit. Now that I look at the code more closely, it will *always* be of 6 elements.

Comment: Guys see why I use selection sort --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322530/control-a-loop-stopping-it-for-a-certain-interval-of-time

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the sort() method on your array. LIke this:
arr.sort()

Comment: yes, but I dont think that the problem is in the sorting function, because it works in other cases. And I don't want to use the sort function.

Comment: why don't you want to use it?

Comment: JavaScript arrays are slow by their nature and in your case, where you need to sort up to 100 values use of ffast sorting algorythms is redundant because iterations you save don't make up for weight of each iteration.

Comment: Just calling `sort` doesn't do the trick here, though. See Kooilnc's answer.

Comment: Guys see why I use selection sort --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322530/control-a-loop-stopping-it-for-a-certain-interval-of-time